# Meaning of "like a heartbeat, keepalive, or other static/monitoring system"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

If I have given feedback on some product like below

> Me: Super useless,
>   Description: Who will add properties here like ContentLenght, ContentType.. etc
>
> Reply: Someone who needs to send the same thing every
>   time, like a heartbeat, keepalive, or other static/monitoring system.

What is them meaning of reply from other person I not able to make out

Link to thread: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/631

Note: Heading now I changed "Super useless" to "Missing Properties like ContentLenght, ContentType"

Thank you.

Comment: Your scenario is not at all clear.  A "keep-alive" is programming jargon for a small periodic interaction that informs a process or device that a listener or consumer is still active, a signal to keep a communications link open. A "heartbeat" is also used in programming to refer to a virtual  "pulse", a signal of some kind, to enable synchronization of some sort. They are "automatic".  Are you the "someone" there? Is that really a *reply* you received, or a statement made to someone else about your feedback? Have you left any words out of it?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - To be clear scenario you can visit the real tread https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/631,  Thank you for useful information.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Not getting your points, you are being so tough.

Comment: I don't understand the question. *Very bad* is not a question but a statement. (Or possibly a reply of its own.) The conversation doesn't make sense. (And if I follow the link in your comment, *very bad* never appears anywhere.)

Comment: @JasonBassford - To be more clear [see this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/631). There First I said "super useless"  than I updated to "Missing info..etc" you will see that if you scroll that post to down. Instead of saying "super useless"  in this question I mention "very bad". This is Feedback not question.

Comment: Okay . . . but "super useless" is also not a *question* to which you can have a *reply*. Here, it was the title of a discussion topic, and not your actual question. As stated in the current answer, your *question* was "Who will add properties here?" So, the *answer* was "*Someone* who needs [certain things]." It's not clear what your confusion here is. What specific part of that response is unclear? Is it a particular word or phrase?

Comment: @JasonBassford - Thank you. I did not understand _like a heartbeat, keepalive, or other static/monitoring system_ & why he mention this _Someone who needs to send the same thing every time_.

Comment: Well. Question: *Who will add properties here?* Answer: *(The person who will add properties is) Someone who needs to send the same thing every time.* Question: *What types of things would such a person need to send every time?* Answer: *(Things) like a heartbeat, keepalive, or other static/monitoring system (i.e., things that are repetitive but only need to be defined once).* But I can't explain the programming portion beyond that, just the grammar.

Answer (score 5):

It's an answer to your original question, "Who will add properties here". I am not familiar with the programming environment in question, but the answer seems to answer you that one would normally set those properties if they need to be sent over and over again. One example is if you're generating a heartbeat message, where the same message is sent repeatedly, so it would be useful to set those properties only once rather than every time.

By the way, I would seriously think about how you title your questions. Your original question title in that exchange ("Super useless") was not only not helpful to people searching for the question, but is also antagonistic to anybody who might answer you. I would not expect to get a lot of useful replies to that sort of question. Your question here also has a title ("Meaning of sentence I come across") that's not very useful. You'll get more and better answers if you give better question titles.

Comment: "Super Useless" wasn't really a question that was feedback. I realized this is wrong than I changed it to something else. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I am not sure whether your answer is going in right direction or not. First glance I though that person is telling me "You are someone who sends same thing always" mean negative feedback.

Comment: No, that's not what he was trying to get across, and I didn't say that is what he was saying. He answered your question straightforwardly (if a bit tersely). He didn't mention your question title. I am the one who suggested you might want to think about giving your questions better and less antagonistic titles. It was a suggestion intended to help you get better answers in the future, obviously not necessary (because both he and I answered your questions despite their titles). Feel free to ignore the advice if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got answer from the same person who made me confused.

If a program named "Program1" is very important and must be executing all the time, sometimes a different program named "Program2" is created to inquire " Program1 every 5 minutes and report back to a user if Program1 is not running.

Every time Program2 makes this request to Program1, the message it sends is "Are you alive?". That message is always the same length.

> Who will add properties here like ContentLenght, ... [to the
>   DefaultRequestHeaders]?

Program2 will, as its a static monitoring system.